# FosUserBundle confirmation email doesn't work with swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, config, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

I want to use the fosuserbundle functionality to send confirmation email and retrieve password etc ... But it is not working. I'm currently working in `dev environment` on LAMP. I think It could be a config.yml issue but I tried everything...

I assume my config.yml file has to be cleaned up but I'm not sure about what I can delete and what I can't.

Here is my way too large `config.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: fr

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_translator:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslator # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_loggable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoLoggable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mappingmapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_tree:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTree # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            softdeleteable: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

#Login using email
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

# FOSUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
    # Permet de définir quel service de mail utiliser
    # On utilise twig_swift pour pouvoir envoyer un email en HTML
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
        user_manager: pugx_user_manager
    # Permet de renseigner le nouveau formulaire d'inscription
    registration:
        form:
            type: app_user_registration
        # Permet la validation automatique du compte par envoi d'un email
        confirmation:
            template: UserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
            enabled:    true
            from_email:
                address:        gauthiercoste@gmail.com
                sender_name:    Gauthier Coste
    resetting:
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        gauthiercoste@gmail.com
                sender_name:    Abracadavrac

pugx_multi_user:
  users:
    standard_user:
        entity: 
          class: UserBundle\Entity\StandardUser
        registration:
          form: 
            type: UserBundle\Form\RegistrationStandardUserType
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
    seller:
        entity: 
          class: UserBundle\Entity\Seller
        registration:
          form: 
            type: UserBundle\Form\RegistrationSellerType
            name: fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
          template: UserBundle:Registration:registerProStep1.html.twig

assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

`parameters.yml` :

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: xxxxxxxxxx
    database_user: root
    database_password: xxxxxxxxxx
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    mailer_password: xxxxxxxxxx
    secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My registration process is in my controller RegistrationStandardUserController.php

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        //Form creation based on my user entity
        $user = new StandardUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationStandardUserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user       ->setEnabled(true);
            $em         ->persist($user);
            $em         ->flush();
            if (!$user) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
            } else {
                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Félicitation '.$user->getFirstName().', vous êtes inscrit');
                $this->authenticateUser($user);
            }
        }else if($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()){
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Il y a une erreur dans le formulaire d\'inscription');
        }

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: Check `config_dev.yml`. By default there is `swiftmailer: disable_delivery: false`.

Comment: OOPS.  That was my setting.  Default is `disable_delivery: true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `confirmation mail is triggered by the REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` event of `FosUserBundle`. In order to send the confirmation mail, I had to :

- Activate the confirmation in config.yml
- configure swift_mailer
- dispense the REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event in my controller

When the controller is overrided, we must not forget to dispense the events.

```
$event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);
```

Comment: In which namespace is the FormEvent class?